# How to continue bash loop?

Tags: bash, macos, algorithm, loops

I'm currently facing an issue which I can't solve. Writing the bash script on Mac OS Catalina.
Loop goes through the truth statement, but after facing a false statement it stuck on it.

**Task**
*%Do something%* if the current day in a loop is a workday.

**Code**

```
# Set initial dates
starting_date=2020-02-10
ending_date=2020-02-24
current_date=$starting_date

#What is the day of the week of this day
current_date_wd=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%u )

#Loop in the set date range
while [ "$current_date" != "$ending_date" ]; 
do
  if [ "$current_date_wd" != "6" ] && [ "$current_date_wd" != "7" ]
  then

# Echo the current workday
    echo 'Today is '$current_date' and it-s a '$current_date_wd'-s day'

# Increment by 1d
    current_date=`date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%Y-%m-%d`

# Calculate day of week
    current_date_wd=$( date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%u )
  else

# Increment
    current_date=`date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%Y-%m-%d`

# Skip
    echo 'skip'
    continue
  fi
done
```

The first part of the output is right. Loop goes trough the days and shows the message. But after meeting the false condition loop doesn't go back for checking the statement.
**Output**

```
Today is 2020-02-10 and it-s a 1-s day
Today is 2020-02-11 and it-s a 2-s day
Today is 2020-02-12 and it-s a 3-s day
Today is 2020-02-13 and it-s a 4-s day
Today is 2020-02-14 and it-s a 5-s day
skip
skip
skip
skip
skip
skip
skip
skip
skip
```

**Expected**

```
Today is 2020-02-10 and it-s a 1-s day
Today is 2020-02-11 and it-s a 2-s day
Today is 2020-02-12 and it-s a 3-s day
Today is 2020-02-13 and it-s a 4-s day
Today is 2020-02-14 and it-s a 5-s day
skip
skip
Today is 2020-02-17 and it-s a 1-s day
Today is 2020-02-18 and it-s a 2-s day
Today is 2020-02-19 and it-s a 3-s day
Today is 2020-02-20 and it-s a 4-s day
Today is 2020-02-21 and it-s a 5-s day
skip
skip
```

Why "continue" did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to update **current_date_wd** in else part, here is the working solution.

```
starting_date=2020-02-10
ending_date=2020-02-24
current_date=$starting_date

#What is the day of the week of this day
current_date_wd=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%u )

#Loop in the set date range
while [ "$current_date" != "$ending_date" ]; 
do
  if [ "$current_date_wd" != "6" ] && [ "$current_date_wd" != "7" ]
  then

    # Echo the current workday
    echo 'Today is '$current_date' and it-s a '$current_date_wd'-s day'

    # Increment by 1d
    current_date=`date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%Y-%m-%d`

    # Calculate day of week
    current_date_wd=$( date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%u )
  else

    # Increment
    current_date=`date -j -v +1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%Y-%m-%d`
    current_date_wd=$( date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$current_date" +%u )

    # Skip
    echo 'skip'
    continue
  fi
done
```